# No lineitems or addresses when extracting customer orders using C# in VirtoCommerce

Tags: c#, virtocommerce

I have a problem with extraction of customer orders.

When I do the following

```
    var orderModule = new OrderModuleApi(apiClient);
    var orders = orderModule.OrderModuleSearch("full", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I expect that each order returned has lineItems and addresses. but there is none. Am I doing something wrong here? All orders that are returned contains the correct TotalSum and such - it is only the LineItems and Addresses that are missing even though the order has both LineItems and addresses.

Actually no matter what I write as criteriaResponseGroup, full/withItems or even somethingRandom then I get the same number of orders back - which I guess must be wrong behaviour? Unless I am using the api wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass "Full" as responseGroup value.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Tried it out but it didnt help, still no addresses or lineitems on the orders.

Answer (score 0):

The Search method in the OrderModuleController had a model binder which was added for the old storefront version. It should be replaced with [FromUri]:

```
public IHttpActionResult Search([FromUri]coreModel.SearchCriteria criteria)
```

Please pull the latest version from the dev-storefront branch and try again.

Comment: Fixed it by creating a custom module that does this. Thanks for the answer :)